# Change connection from MySql DB to Oracle DB

Tags: database, oracle, groovy

I need help here in connecting to oracle db. The script used to connect to a mySql previously. I am pasting the code for the (my sql) db. Excuse my amateur skills in groovy.

```
def con = jdbcModuleObj.connectToDb("jdbc:oracle://$DbIp/$DbName","$DbUsername","$DbPassword", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the connection is made to the default 1521 Oracle database port, you can try the following:

```
def con = jdbcModuleObj.connectToDb("jdbc:oracle:thin:@$DbIp:1521:$DbName","$DbUsername","$DbPassword", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
```

For details, check [the Oracle jdbc driver doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)